# Docker not allowing use of System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement

Tags: asp.net, docker, asp.net-core

My application keeps crashing

```
        // domain connection
        PrincipalContext LDAPDomain = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, LDAP_DOMAIN);

        // checking existance of user
        UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(LDAPDomain, username);
```

The error message says

```
DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'activeds.dll' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (0x8007007E)
```

The code works fine when running in IIS but in Docker, I get this crash and I am not sure how to resolve it.

I've done the following

> docker cp C:\Windows\System32\activeds.dll
>   :/C:/Windows/System32

In build Events in visual Studio, (Pre-Build)

> XCOPY /Y "C:\Windows\System32\activeds.dll" "$(TargetDir)"
>
> REGSVR32 C:\Windows\System32\activeds.dll (Console for Docker)